# How to convert a German word to English word in Big Query SQL

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, translation

I need to convert German words to English using Google Big Query SQL.
e.g: 'Verwaltung' (German) in my source file should be reflected as 'administration' (English) in my Big Query table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [remote functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/remote-functions) with BigQuery. In your query, you invoque a remote functions (a [Cloud Functions 2nd generation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/2nd-gen/overview)) and you invoke [translation API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/translate.googleapis.com/overview*) on each line of your query.